# Find the Big O time complexity of the code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am fairly familiar with simple time complexity regarding constant, linear, and quadratic time complexities. In simple code segments like:

```
int i = 0;  
i + 1;
```

This is constant. So O(1). And in:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

This is linear since it iterates n+1 times, but for Big O time complexities we remove the constant, so just O(N). In nested for loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
```

I get how we multiply n+1 by n and reach a time complexity of O(N^2). My issue is with slightly more complex versions of this. So, for example:

```
S = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  for (j = 0; j < N*N; j++) 
    S++;
```

In such a case, would I be multiplying n+1 by the inner for loop time complexity, of which I presume is n^2? So the time complexity would be O(n^3)?

Another example is:

```
 S = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < i*i; j++) 
     for (k = 0; k < j; k++) 
       S++;
```

In this case, I expanded it and wrote it out and realized that the inner, middle for loop seems to be running at an n*n time complexity, and the most inner for loop at the pace of j, which is also nxn. So in that case, would I be multiplying n+1 x n^2 x n^2, which would give me O(n^5)?

Also, I am still struggling to understand what kind of code has logarithmic time complexity. If someone could give me an algorithm or segment of code that performs at log(n) or n log(n) time complexity, and explain it, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I was wondering whether my answers for the bottom two code segments was correct. Also, any possible explanation on logarithmic complexity and examples.

Comment: The complexity for the last part will be O(n^5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your answers are correct.

Logarithmic time complexity typically occurs when you're reducing the size of the problem by a constant factor on every iteration.

Here's an example:

`for (int i = N; i >= 0; i /= 2) { .. do something ... }`

In this for-loop, we're dividing the problem size by `2` on every iteration. We'll need approximately `log_2(n)` iterations prior to terminating. Hence, the algorithm runs in `O(log(n))` time.

Another common example is the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which searches a sorted interval for a value. In this procedure, we remove half of the values on each iteration (once again, we're reducing the size of the problem by a constant factor of `2`). Hence, the runtime is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped.